# Find when right click occurs, stop the effects of it and replace with shift click in java or python

Tags: java, python, macos, hotkeys, right-click

Is there anyway to ignore a right click as it happens, and then replace it with a shift click at the spot of where the right click was in Java/Python? Note that this should happen globally throughout the entire computer. Also note that this is in Mac OSX.

Thanks,

Odin

Comment: That's an extremely low level feature, so standard java/python themselves are the wrong choice for such things. You may be able to find some packages for these things otherwise you'll have to write C code and interop that with your program.

Comment: This is not possible in Java/Python.  I'm not even sure if a native OSX "hackie" has access to this.  Can you take a step back and explain _why_ you want this functionality?

Answer (score 0):

This depends on OS or Window Manager implementation. For this to
work there should be some kind of "hook" into these events(e.g. right click), 
along with the context it was fired(e.g. right click on the Desktop/Folder/File).

But it is highly improbable you could choose the language you would implement
such a thing, even if it is possible on your OS.